# How to efficiently apply XOR to two integer arrays?

Tags: algorithm, math, mathematical-optimization

I have two arrays as follows:

```
A = [1,2,35,4,32,1,2,56,43,2,21]
B = [1,2,35,4,32,1,2,56,43,45,1]
```

As we can see that A and B has initial subsequence same till element 43. My end goal is to calculate the XOR of last uncommon elements of both of these sequences. Here, my goal is to find XOR of `{2,21,45,1}`.

Currently, my approach is to store running XOR of both of these arrays in two separate Arrays (say, RESA[], & RESB[]) and then when ever I am asked to find the the XOR of A[0-10] & B[0-9], I just quickly perform a single XOR operation as follows:

```
RESA[10] ^ RESB[9]
```

This works because while XORing, common elements cancels out.

My problem here is, what **if in every query a threshold T is passed**. For example, in this case, if the threshold passed is `32` the I have to filter elements that are less than 32 in both A and B and then apply XORing of all such elements. This definitely increases the complexity, and I cannot apply my earlier logic of keeping running XORs of elements.

**Please let me know if you have any ideas on how to leverage XOR properties to come up with a constant time approach as before when there was no thresholds.**

Comment: Is the threshold, T, always a power of 2 (in which case this is easy), or was the example of 32 just an unfortunate choice ?

Comment: @PaulR Could be any number. Not necessarily a power of 2. However, I would like to know how a power of 2 makes it easier.

Comment: @user3243499 Power of 2 grows very quickly hence you can calculate this answer for each power of 2 uptill the limit you want, and you will be able to solve it for very large numbers very efficiently.

Comment: @user3243499: I may have been hasty in my assertion that powers of 2 values for T are easy - I was thinking you could just make out the bottom log2(T) bits but of course that does't remove the effect of the higher order bits (in mitigation I think I wrote this before I'd had coffee this morning!).

Comment: I must say that the explanation is quite unclear. First, you state that your end goal is to take XOR of uncommon elements. But then you introduce a threshold value and state that you have to take XOR of uncommon elements that are greater than this threshold in both the arrays. So your first statement of "end goal" was it incomplete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already worked you that you can find the XOR of the uncommon elements by computing the XOR of every element in the two arrays.

XOR is a commutative and associative operator so we can reorder the arrays in any way we like and still have the same total XOR.

In particular, we can reverse sort each array, and then compute the running XOR of each sorted array.

With this preprocessing we can now compute the XOR of all elements above a threshold by using binary search on each sorted array to find how many elements above T, followed by a lookup into the running XOR array.

This gives an O(logn) complexity for each query.

### Extension

The above answer assumes that the query is just the threshold 32: i.e. the start is always 0, and the end is always the length of each sequence.  (I assume this because the question says the final goal is to compute the XOR of all uncommon elements.)

If the query also consisted of the start and end of the region to be XORed I would suggest a different approach that requires more storage (because it requires all queries to be buffered and sorted):

1. Sort all the queries by threshold
2. Maintain a segment tree of the XOR for each sequence, intialized to 0.
3. Add the values into the sequences in decreasing order, and perform the queries as soon as all values above their threshold have been inserted.

For example, the segment tree for a sequence C=[1,2,35,4,32,1,2,56] would contain:

```
1
2
35
4
32
1
2
56
1^2
35^4
32^1
2^56
1^2^35^4
32^1^2^56
1^2^35^4^32^1^2^56
```

Once we have these values we can compute the XOR of any range using log(n) steps.  For example, suppose we wanted to compute the XOR of C[1:3] = [2,35,4].  We can do this by xoring 2 with 35^4.

Comment: "No idea" why this has been accepted - how does this allow to answer queries like `XOR of A[0-10] & B[0-9] [… using threshold] 32`, with A and B available for preprocessing, (0?, 10, 9, 32) constituting the query? Binary search through *(len(A)+len(B))×|{v in A or B }|* precomputed results?

Comment: @greybeard I've added some explanation of how to solve the problem if the start and end are also part of the query.

Comment: Point 2 and 3 seems not clear. Could you please give some brief examples so that it becomes more clear. For instance, when you say, maintain a segment tree for each sequence - what sequence are being referred here ?